# Turbulence in fundamental particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, particle-physics, turbulence

We know that when fluids move fast enough they create turbulence. So, my question is: Is it true for mass-less or negligible mass particles also, do they also show turbulence when accelerated to extremely high speeds?

Comment: In what medium?

Comment: knzhou I am particularly interested in vacuum because it is less hard than other cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Estakhr's decomposition](http://meetings.aps.org/link/BAPS.2016.TSF.H1.8) is a mathematical technique to separate the average and fluctuating parts of Relativistic Turbulent Flows.

$${\overline{U}^{\mu}=\lim_{\tau\rightarrow\infty}({\frac{1}{\tau}}\int_{\tau_{o}}^{\tau}U^{\mu} d\tau)}$$

Where the $\tau$ is proper time.

$${U^{\mu}=\overline{U}^{\mu}+U'^{\mu}}$$

Where the $\overline{U}^{\mu}$ denotes the proper time average called steady component and $U'^{\mu}$ is fluctuating part.

There are **No** turbulence، When fluctuating part is equal to zero.

$$U'^{\mu}=0$$

Comment: I really liked your answer, but it would be amazing if you could explain the integral and how it is derived (maybe not derivation but intuitive sense of it)